# How to deal with first order complex differential equation?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, complex, code-request

I am trying to solve these two equations but find an error of fewer than the dependent variable and list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. I don't know what should I do? If anyone can resolve this, will be appreciated.

```
A1 = 1;
B1 = 0;
del0 = 1.50;
g0 = .0003;
dela = -1.5;(*Subscript[\[CapitalDelta], L] ; Laser-Lower polariton \
detuning*)
ome = 3.014;
ome1 = .125;
k1 = 0.1;
P0 = 20;
kex = .02;
kL = (k1 + kex)/2 - del0*(k1 - kex)/(2*ome);
Gma = 0.0001;
sol = DSolveValue[{a1'[t] - I*dela*a1[t] - 
      I*g0*(1 - del0/ome)*A1*(b1[t] + Conjugate[b1[t]])/2*a1[t] - 
      I*P0*(1 - del0/(2*ome))/Sqrt[2] - 
      I*P0*g0*B1*((b1[t] + Conjugate[b1[t]])/2)/(Sqrt[2]*ome) + 
      kL/2*a1[t] + (k1 - kex)*g0/ome*B1*(b1[t] + Conjugate[b1[t]])/2*
       a1[t] == 0, 
    b1'[t] + I*ome1*b1[t] - I*g0*(1 - del0/ome)*A1*Abs[a1[t]]^2/2 - 
      I*P0*g0*B1*((a1[t] + Conjugate[a1[t]])/2)/(Sqrt[2]*ome) + 
      Gma*b1[t]/2 == 0, a1[t] == 1, b1[t] == 0}, a1, b1, t] // Chop
Plot[{Evaluate[Abs[a1[t]^2]] /. sol}, {t, 0, 500}]
```

Comment: A couple of obvious problems. If you are trying to solve differential equations for `a1[t]` and `b1[t]` then giving it initial conditions `a1[t]==1,b1[t]==0` sort of defeats the process. Probably you meant `a1[0]==1,b1[0]==0` or something similar. Next, you finish up your `DSolveValue` with `...a1,b1,t]` and that almost certainly needs to be `...{a1,b1},t]` Next, for `DSolve` and `DSolveValue` giving it exact rational constants often enables it to select more powerful solution algorithms. But for a problem of this complexity you may want to use `NDSolveValue` instead, with the usual changes.

Comment: @Thanks Bill. Fully satisfied with your answer.

Comment: Your use of `Conjugate` could be replaced by `Re`: `FullSimplify[Re[z] == ((z + Conjugate[z])/2)]`.  As Bill hints, I'd be surprised if `DSolve` has algorithms to solve ODEs that have `Conjugate` or `Re` in them, so you probably have to use numerical methods.